# Incorrect path to file

Tags: java, exception, input, stream, output

I don't know why but `outStream = new FileOutputStream(file)` and `inStream = new FileInputStream(new File(file1.getName()))` throw an exception. I have no idea what to do.

Here's some code of this:

```
        File tempf = new File(cmds[1]); //cmds is a String with filename cmds[1] and  pathname cmds[2] where to move the file
        File tempw = new File(cmds[2]);
        if(!tempf.isAbsolute() || !tempw.isAbsolute()){//here i make paths absolute
            tempf = new File(tempf.getAbsolutePath());
            tempw = new File(tempw.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        String from = cmds[1];
        String where = cmds[2];
        File file1 = tempf;
        File file2 = new File (tempw.toString() + "/" + new File(cmds[1]).getName());
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            inStream = new FileInputStream(new File(file1.getName())); //throws an exception
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file2); //throws an exception too
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
            int length;
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            if (inStream != null)
                inStream.close();
            if (outStream != null)
                outStream.close();
            file1.delete();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("permission denied");
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("incorrect syntax");
    }
    continue;
}
```

Looks like everything should work fine but it doesn't. I am getting

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Maxim\IdeaProjects\Testing\OneDrive\1234.txt
```

But as I see it's wrong path. Real path is `C:\Users\Maxim\OneDrive`

UPD! It's found out that the problem is that `getAbsolutePath()` returns a path where the project is, but it's not the path I need. I need `C:\Users\Maxim\OneDrive` BUT it returns `C:\Users\Maxim\IdeaProjects\Testing\OneDrive` BUT! `.../Testng` doesn't have OneDrive!

Comment: Show the EXCEPTION!!!

Comment: The great thing about exceptions, especially standard library ones, is that they tell you why they happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructors for FileInputStream and FileOutputStream throw errors if there is a problem accessing the file, like if it doesn't exist. To stop it from throwing a FileNotFoundException, make sure you create the file before instantiating a FileInput/OutputStream object.

```
try{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Look at the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream(java.io.File)).